# Where to post my project for testing [php]

Tags: php, testing

I am making php application, and I am wondering where to post my project to make it public, so a lot of developers can test my project and reveal some bugs or something else?

Sorry if this question is stupid.. :/

Comment: publish your php application online :)

Comment: And I want to share code

Comment: you want to share the php application or just php codes?

Comment: I want to share both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upload it on github although it is a VCS still people can look at your work and also they can make changes

Answer (score 2):

A website? Host it on a free server like [000webhost.com](http://www.000webhost.com) and share the link on famous websites like stackoverflow :)

Comment: How to get people downloading and testing?

Comment: You can try uploading your code there, from there you can share your project on different platforms. And people on that site will see your project once it's on the site :) Additionally, you can try joining the chat groups here on StackOverflow and share the link of you GitHub project